# Regex pattern does not work with 'or'

Tags: python, regex, grouping

I need to parse DHCP log data which is like below:

```
2013-11-15 09:42:02 localhost dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.51.1.242 to 00:1e:8c:21:83:a0 (Hostname Unsuitable for Printing) via eth2
```

I wrote a regex pattern to gather all matched values and it like this:

```
(?P<date>[\d{2,4}-]*[\d{2}:\s]*)\s(?P<host>\S+)\s*(?P<facility>\s*\S*:)\s*((?P<action>DHCP*\S*)\s*|(?P<mac>([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]){2})\s*|(?P<message>\S*)\s*|(\s*))*
```

After `re.search(regex, text).groupdict()` command it gives me this dict:

```
{u'facility': u'dhcpd:', u'host': u'localhost', u'date': u'2013-11-15 09:42:02', u'mac': u'00:1e:8c:21:83:a0', u'action': u'DHCPACK', u'message': u''}
```

As it is seen that every single item returns me correct match but message part which placed in parentheses and I tried with too many variations to get it. `(?P<message>\((.*)\))` pattern works fine and returns `{u'message': u'(Hostname Unsuitable for Printing)'}` if I use it as single otherwise It does not match at all.

I stuck with this and really need help.

Comment: Have you tried https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylogsparser ?

Comment: what exactly do you want to get?

Comment: @thg435 nope! I did not try it even do not know that! Will have a look. Tnx.

Comment: @akaRem I would like to parse DHCPd log and cast it into a python dict by grouping with regex.

Comment: @FatihKaratana Do you know that `\S*` does not match `(Hostname Unsuitable for Printing)`? You need to look forward for closing bracket or you need to know length.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using so many `|` operands. I stripped them out and used `\s+` as delimiters and `$` to match the end of string as a delimiter for the message but this works for me:

```
import re
text = r'2013-11-15 09:42:02 localhost dhcpd: DHCPACK on 10.51.1.242 to 00:1e:8c:21:83:a0 (Hostname Unsuitable for Printing) via eth2'
my_regexp = r'^(?P<date>[\d{2,4}-]*[\d{2}:\s]*)\s+(?P<host>\S+)\s+(?P<facility>\s*\S*):(\s+(?P<action>DHCP*\S*).+(?P<mac>([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]){2})\s+(?P<message>.*))*$'
print re.search( my_regexp, text).groupdict()
```

Output:

```
{'facility': 'dhcpd', 'host': 'localhost', 'date': '2013-11-15 09:42:02', 'mac': '00:1e:8c:21:83:a0', 'action': 'DHCPACK', 'message': '(Hostname Unsuitable for Printing) via eth2'}
```

Comment: thank you for your response.

I use | operands to get a value either define or None. If It does not come out because of | operand I get a None otherwise regex will not work. Data format is not produced always in a same way. Your way will not work if a data like this will appear: '''2013-11-15 09:42:02 localhost dhcpd: DHCPACK to 10.51.1.207 (00:13:20:d7:22:a7) via eth2'''